# Buscar y seleccionar un item dentro de un campo combobox de un Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tengo un datagridview ya definido con varios campos y uno de ellos es un combobox dentro del datagrid el cual alimento desde sql server, el problema es que cuando intento cargar el datagrid con la consulta de sql no puedo buscar dentro de ese combo y seleccionar específicamente el item que traigo desde sql server.

De esta manera cargo los datos al combobox:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cuenta = dgvDetalleEntrada.Columns["Cuenta"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
cuenta.DataSource = entrada.CargarCuenta();
cuenta.DisplayMember = "idcuenta";
```

Quisiera saber de que forma puedo hacerlo, gracias.

Comment: Podrías colocar tu código?, sería más fácil ver que es lo que sucede...

Comment: entonces no le estas pasando el query a esa columna combobox o es lo que se entiende con tu descripcion

Comment: Acabo de editar las entradas @J.Rodríguez, a ver si pueden ayudarme.

Comment: @RamónZoquier El problema es que solo estas asignando el `DisplayMember` debes asignar el valor también: `cuenta.ValueMember = "idcuenta";` o puede probar: `dataGridView1.Rows[indice].Cells["ComboColumn"].Value = 1;`

Comment: Otra cosa que debe tomar en cuenta es que tenga asignada la propiedad `DataPropertyName` así : `cuenta.DataPropertyName = "idcuenta";`

Comment: @J.Rodríguez y como lo asigno el item que traigo desde SQL Server al combobox?

Comment: @RamónZoquier Vuelve a leer mi comentario, ahí puse como hacerlo

Comment: @J.Rodríguez muchas gracias, me funciono de la forma en que me sugeriste.

Comment: @RamónZoquier me alegra que te haya sido de ayuda.